# A schema-less hierarchical database where only the "leafs" are documents

Tags: database, data-structures, nosql, rdbms, graph-databases

My data structure is tree-like, where the branches are pure keys, and only the leafs are schema less documents.

Example:

```js
keyA
    KeyA_1
        KeyA_1A{
            key: value,
            key: value,
            key: valeu
        }
        KeyA_1B
            KeyA_1B_1{
               key: value,
               key: value,
               key: value
            }  
   KeyA_2
        KeyA_2A{
            key: value,
            key: value
        }
KeyB
    KeyB_1{
         key: value,
         key: value,
         key: valeu
    }
    KeyB_2{
         key: value
    }
```

Which database is the right for me?

Comment: In leafs you have constraint? (foreign keys)

Comment: No relation between leafs

Answer (score 1):

I think that the data structure you described here is not how it supposed to looks like in the DB, it's just how your application considers it.

If you want to store it, so later it can be easily travelable, I suggest to save your tree as a list of nodes which each node is a model (row/document), that have the following fields:

- id (pk)
- key (if you still need it)
- next (fk, nullable)
- data (json, optional)

This way you can build your tree and travel it till you'll meet with `next = null` with the tree-traversal technique you prefer.

Regards the DB itself, as said, you can choose the one you prefer (rational/non-rational, Postgres v9.2+ or MySql v5.7+ can be a good solution for you because they haves JSONB/JSON field support for your data.